# ICS split call/notification volume

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, volume

My app is able to set sound profiles like Meeting mode, night mode, normal... In each one you may select the volume value for incomming calls and for notifications. For example, Night mode has a volume for calls (in case I have an emergency call) and none for notification (in case a late email or whatsapp is received it will not wake me up).
It works pretty good so far but I found that it fails in Android 4 Ice Cream Sandwich. For some not understandable reason for me ICS ties together ring volume and notifications volume. So at night you will also hear annoying spams or SMSs.

Any idea how to split/untie them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICS+ has merged the ringer and notification volumes into one volume. There is no way via code to unlink these volume controls. However, you can wire up a adjust the new unified notification volume based on conditions. I use this in Audio Control when someone calls it applies a pre-chosen volume setting to mimic the ringer volume and adjusts back to the prior setting after the call has ended.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Android 4 ICS: I'm a pilot and sometimes I'm on standby (also at night) When that happens I don't want to be woken up by an incoming mail or text message, but phone calls have to come through of course. The **paid version** of an app called "[Audio Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matthew.rice.volume.master&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5tYXR0aGV3LnJpY2Uudm9sdW1lLm1hc3RlciJd)" by [Matthew Rice](http://www.mobiletrialware.com/) solved this problem for me. It allows me to sleep undisturbed by text messages or mails, but a phone call or my alarm will wake me up!

Answer (score 0):

ICS (4.0.4) on my RAZR has notification and ringtone volumes as separate sliders with no way to link them.
The volume rocker controls whatever volume is "active", which means ringtone when the phone is idle, call volume when on a call, and media/app volume when running an app or listening to media.

Comment: well, my problem is the opposite. incoming call and notification have the same slider. So it is not possible to hear incoming calls and mute notifications at the same time.